# How to Center a bordered content when converting from html to pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have an html page with contents inside a border with 7px which has to div, the parent and child div, I am trying to convert it to pdf, but when I do so, the page is aligning more to the right, leaving a huge space to the left. But when the same page is viewed in html, it is correctly centered. Th

What I need to achieve is to center the border and its content in the PDF file. The parent div has the following css

````
``` #wrapper{
    width: 740px;
    /*margin: 2px auto;*/
    margin: auto;
    /*border: solid  red;*/
    height: 1000px;
    page-break-after: avoid;
}```
````

and the child div has the following css

````
```#maincontent{
    border: solid 7px black;
    /*margin: 2px auto 100px;*/
    /*margin: 2px auto;*/
    margin: auto;
    height: 98.2%;
    /*width: 98%;*/
    width: 720px;
    display: block;
    page-break-before: avoid;
    break-after: avoid;
}```
````

Comment: Do you create the pdf with the browsers print functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The laravel-dompdf is a nice library but does it is not great when dealing with css, so there is a **wkhtmltopdf** which is a CLI tool that uses the WebKit rendering engine. There is a PHP library named **laravel-snappy** which created a wrapper to wkhtmltopdf and converts html to pdf/image, available for almost all operating systems. The full explanation and link to manual documentation is available at [link]https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Comment: thank you for the information i myself just started on Laravel and to be honest as there is not a lot of information on pdf this will help me. my original answer was based on CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

With MPDF do not style inside your HTML print page it will not work. Add style to your controller or .CSS or add styling above your HTML not inside. Please note the row style is !important you need to add that to your style.
Also note the bootstrap not all bootstrap versions is MPDF friendly. Version 3.4.1 work for me.

```
<?php
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$stylesheet = '<style>
    .row {
        margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
    }
    .wrapper{
    width: 740px;
    /*margin: 2px auto;*/
    margin: auto;
    /*border: solid  red;*/
    height: 1000px;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    }
    .maincontent{
    border: solid 7px black;
    /*margin: 2px auto 100px;*/
    /*margin: 2px auto;*/
    margin: auto;
    height: 98.2%;
    /*width: 98%;*/
    width: 720px;
    display: block;
    page-break-before: avoid;
    break-after: avoid;
    }
</style>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML(view('/print/print_jobcard', $data), \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
$mpdf->Output($data['jobcard'][0]['job_number'].'.pdf', 'D');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div >
   
    <br style="height: 15mm; margin: 0;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8"><h4>Date</h4></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8"><h4 style= "text-align:center"> Lorem Ipson</h4></div>
    </div>
 
    <br style="height: 30mm; margin: 0;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4"><h4>Name</h4></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4"><h4>Email</h4></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><h4>Tel</h4></div>
    </div>
   
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using DomPDF library

Comment: the basics will stay the same use styling external. DomPDF support more CSS but if i understand correctly it is slower, but the end result will be pdf. if you can give me your code than i will try and implement my code to test.

Comment: copy my  <style> and implement in your code and see if it helps

Comment: Did not workm tried to google it seems with DomPDF or there are issued when converting html to pdf, advised to check other libraries

Comment: Sorry, Alluma try using mpdf there is not a lot of help full content when it comes to pdf. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much, i appreciate a lot. But, i found a very useful link which has helped me a lot,seems the laravel-dompdf wrapper has some issues when converting html to pdf, there is another wrapper just the same as  **barryvdh/laravel-dompdf**, but it called laravel-snappy **barryvdh/laravel-snappy**, i used this wrapper and worked like a charm

Comment: I found the issued and the suggested solutions by @Corez64 at [link] https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-dompdf-not-using-css

Comment: Thanx @Alluma I upvoted you comments, for the next person to see this as helpful.